# Pre tag with contenteditable=true - new lines are not preserved in element's text() content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `pre` tag that displays text taken from a database (notes for a shopping order). I use the pre tag because it displays new lines.

I use `contenteditable="true"` on it so that users can edit the field, and click a save button to save it.

However upon saving, when I take the field's value using `field.text()`, the new lines are not preserved.

Reproduce:

HTML:

```
<pre id="notes" contenteditable="true">Some

test


Txt

</pre>
```

JS:

```
// Works fine here
console.log($('#notes').text());

// add some text with new lines, then "blur" the text and you can see the issue happening in the log -- new lines not preserved
$('#notes').on('blur', function (e) {
    console.log($('#notes').text());
});
```

*What I am trying but so far haven't succeeded*

```
// When user presses enter on an editable field.
$('#notes').on('keydown', function (e) {


    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // trap the return key being pressed and insert new line at THIS place --- how??? (Possibly not the most elegant solution either)
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6496pke5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use html() instead of text() in order to create a break line on hit Enter.
Using html() will wrap a `<br>` tag into a `<div>` element though, to prevent that behaviour use document.execCommand() method:

```
$('#notes').on('keydown', function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
        return false; 
    }

});
```

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6496pke5/1/

Answer (score 0):

It won't because you are doing

```
console.log($('#notes').text());
```

since when you press `enter` to create a new line `<br>` is added to the markup which will not come in the `textContent` attribute of the `element` of which `.text()` is a short form of.

try instead

```
console.log($('#notes').html());
```

you will see the new lines `<br>` added.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use a hidden tag **pre** and code for event **'blur'** as shown as below.

```
$('#notes-text').text($('#notes').html().replace(/<br>/g, '\n'));
console.log($('#notes-text').text());
```

```js
console.log($('#notes').text());

$('#notes').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
    return false;
  }
});

$('#notes').on('blur', function() {
  $('#notes-text').text($('#notes').html().replace(/<br>/g, '\n'));
  console.log($('#notes-text').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="notes" contenteditable="true">Some

test


Txt

</pre>
<pre id="notes-text" style="display: none;"></pre>
```

Comment: How did you find this old thread :D

Comment: Some problems (questions) never get old  ;-)